# i have element and i want to press keydown up down left right each one the element will translate to diffierent positon

Tags: javascript

i have a class name side-build-boxcontrol-preseve-3d and i try to make controller by pressing key up down left right so the element will go down left right left , i use translate3d property because its css in 3d , but i tried many different way , always not working

```
 import obj from './selection'; //import obj is equal to queryselector

 function transformer(e) {
      let sbcp3d = obj.select('.side-build-boxcontrol-preserve-3d');
      sbcp3d.style.transform = 
      'translate3d(400px,150px,6px)rotatez(30deg)';
         var lastpos = [null, null, null];
         var tx = 0;
         var ty = 0;
         var rz = 0;
         var key = function(e) {
          return e.keyCode;
          }
         var transx = 400,
         transy = 150,
          transz = 6;

          if (key() == 38) {
           console.log('38')
            transx += 100;
             transx = tx;
            lastpos[0] += tx;
           if (lastpos[0] != null) {
              console.log('lastpos[0]+tx')
              lastpos[0] += transx;
               return lastpos[0];
            }
    if (key() == 40) {
        console.log('40');
        transx -= 100;
        transx = tx;
        lastpos[0] -= tx;
        if (lastpos[0] != null) {
            console.log('lastpos[0]')
            lastpos[0] -= transx;
            return lastpos[0];
        }
        if (key() == 37) {
            transy += 100;
            transy = ty;
            ty += lastpos[1];
            if (lastpos[1] !== null) {
                console.log(lastpos[1]);
                lastpos[1] += transy;
                return lastpos[1];
            }
        }
        if (key() == 39) {
            transy -= 100;
            transy = ty;
            ty -= lastpos[1];
            if (lastpos[1] !== null) {
                console.log(lastpos[1]);
                lastpos[1] -= transy;
                return lastpos[1];
            }
        }
        var transform = '(translate3d(' + lastpos[0] + 'px,' + lastpos[1] + 'px,6px)rotatez(' + rz + 'deg)';
        sbcp3d.style.transform = transform;

    }
     }
  }



   module.exports = transformer;

     index.js
   import transformer from './graphic';
    document.addEventListener('keydown'transformer(););
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `return lastpos[0];`，`return lastpos[1];`,`return lastpos[2];`. Because when the code run there, the transformer function is ending,
`var transform = '(translate3d(' + lastpos[0] + 'px,' + lastpos[1] + 'px,6px)rotatez(' + rz + 'deg)';
sbcp3d.style.transform = transform;` won't run.
So it's not working,you can remove `return lastpos[0];` etc and replace `document.addEventListener('keydown'transformer(););` with `document.body.addEventListener('keydown',transformer);`